# Why are most of my backlinks going to HTTP instead of to HTTPS?

Tags: .htaccess

I run a fairly new blog. Recently, I noticed that most of the backlinks to my site are going to the HTTP version, even though I defined HTTPS as the standard version of my website (or so I thought).

These are mostly "crappy" backlinks from automated crawlers, but still. Could there be a mistake with my `.htaccess`?

Here it is:

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[4.0.9]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php80” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit


# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home2/directoryname1/public_html/directoryname2/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home2/directoryname1/public_html/directoryname2/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

I don't remember installing the ReallySimpleSSL plugin. Maybe my hoster did that. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code in `.htaccess`  It looks like it should redirect HTTP to HTTPS for your site.  If you have typed `http://example.com` for your site into your browser and verified that it goes to `https://example.com`, then that is working correctly.

You can't really control how back links are created. These crappy automated back links may be created from domain registration records rather than from a person or crawler that actually visits your site. The system that creates the links may not know if you have HTTPS or not and so creates a HTTP link because pretty much every site has that.

Comment: Hello Stephen, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Yes, if I type http into my browser, it automatically goes to https. So I guess everything is as it should be. And I did not know that about the domain registration records, that's a good point. Again, I really appreciate your input. Have a great day!